# Incorrect Test Count When running Cucumber Scenarios with Failsafe

Tags: maven, cucumber, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am lost with this. I have created some tests(sample shown below) and I run them with Failsafe, but I get incorrect count. For example when I run the scenario shown below I expect Tests Run as 1 but it shows 2 . Could anyone point out where I am going wrong?
The tests are run with a Junit Runner.

Scenario:-

```
  @QA-100 @abc @xyz
  Scenario: Generation of xml file
    Given I have generated a xml file with below details
      | empname| department| 
      | Jordan | Accounts  | 
Then I am able to see the details in the file
```

A part of the pom from 'build' section:-

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>execution</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <projectName>Cucumber Report</projectName>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
          <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.failsafe.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/${test}.*</include>
      </includes>
      <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <configFile>${config}</configFile>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      <source>${java.source.version}</source>
      <target>${java.target.version}</target>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <meminitial>4096m</meminitial>
      <maxmem>8192m</maxmem>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Maven command to run the test:-

```
 mvn clean verify -Dtest=RunTest -Dconfig=local '-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@abc'
```

Failsafe summary xml has these details after test run:-

```
    <completed>2</completed>
    <errors>0</errors>
    <failures>0</failures>
    <skipped>0</skipped>
```

Failsafe and surefire versions:-

```
 <maven.failsafe.version>2.22.2</maven.failsafe.version>
 <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version> 
  <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.11.0</cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version
```

> 

Test run results in console:-

```
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to reproduce your problem.

However one way to create this problem would be to do the following:

1. Keep your features under `src/test/resources`
2. Run `mvn test`
3. Rename your feature file
4. Run `mvn test` again.

In step #2 Maven has copied all resources to the `target` folder. In step #3 it copies the renamed feature file to the `target` folder. So you now have the original and the renamed feature files in the `target` folder. So when running the tests, both feature files will be executed.

Try running `mvn clean test` to clean the `target` folder after renaming files.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question now with more details.

Comment: Currently, if you were to start with an empty project and only this post, would you be able to create your own problem?

Comment: Let me check with an empty project

Comment: M.P. Korstanje,Sorry for late in coming back. I have tried with a new project and failsafe-summary.xml still shows incorrect number though I have run only one scenario. How does failsafe calculate these numbers? I have the scenario and then cucumber step def for each line of the Gherkin

Comment: Try https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton if that works for you, check the differences with your project.